# javascript submit form in an ajax request not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that needs to submit in an ajax request that the user will not see.  When I just go to the page directly it works.  But when I call it in an ajax request it will not submit?

Here's the file that will submit if I go to it directly but not in ajax call:

"testConvertKit.php"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://f.convertkit.com/ckjs/ck.5.js"></script>
<script>
        window.onload = function(){
            document.forms['convertkitform'].submit();
        }
</script>
     
     
     
      <form action="https://app.convertkit.com/forms/hidden....."
        id="convertkitform" 
      class="seva-form formkit-form" method="post" data-sv-form="1613966" data-uid="hidden" data-format="inline" 
      data-version="5" 
      data-options="{&quot;settings&quot;:{&quot;after_subscribe&quot;:{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;message&quot;,&quot;success_message&quot;:&quot;Success! Now check your email to confirm your subscription.&quot;,&quot;redirect_url&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;analytics&quot;:{&quot;google&quot;:null,&quot;facebook&quot;:null,&quot;segment&quot;:null,&quot;pinterest&quot;:null},&quot;modata-optionsdal&quot;:{&quot;trigger&quot;:&quot;timer&quot;,&quot;scroll_percentage&quot;:null,&quot;timer&quot;:5,&quot;devices&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;show_once_every&quot;:15},&quot;powered_by&quot;:{&quot;show&quot;:true,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://convertkit.com?utm_source=dynamic&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=poweredby&amp;utm_content=form&quot;},&quot;recaptcha&quot;:{&quot;enabled&quot;:false},&quot;return_visitor&quot;:{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;show&quot;,&quot;custom_content&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;slide_in&quot;:{&quot;display_in&quot;:&quot;bottom_right&quot;,&quot;trigger&quot;:&quot;timer&quot;,&quot;scroll_percentage&quot;:null,&quot;timer&quot;:5,&quot;devices&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;show_once_every&quot;:15},&quot;sticky_bar&quot;:{&quot;display_in&quot;:&quot;top&quot;,&quot;trigger&quot;:&quot;timer&quot;,&quot;scroll_percentage&quot;:null,&quot;timer&quot;:5,&quot;devices&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;show_once_every&quot;:15}},&quot;version&quot;:&quot;5&quot;}"
       min-width="400 500 600 700 800" style="background-color: rgb(249, 250, 251); border-radius: 4px;">
       <div class="formkit-background" style="opacity: 0.2;"></div>
       <div data-style="minimal">
       <div class="formkit-header" data-element="header" style="color: rgb(77, 77, 77); font-size: 27px; font-weight: 700;">
       <h1>Request Info </h1></div>
       <div class="formkit-subheader" data-element="subheader" style="color: rgb(104, 104, 104); font-size: 18px;">
       <p>Request info hidden form</p></div><ul class="formkit-alert formkit-alert-error" data-element="errors" data-group="alert"></ul>
       <div data-element="fields" data-stacked="false" class="seva-fields formkit-fields">
       <div class="formkit-field">
       <input class="formkit-input" name="email_address" placeholder="Your email address" required="" type="email" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(227, 227, 227); border-radius: 4px; font-weight: 400;" value="<?php echo "someemail@yahoo.com"; ?>"></div>
       <button data-element="submit" class="formkit-submit formkit-submit" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(22, 119, 190); border-radius: 4px; font-weight: 400;"><div class="formkit-spinner"><div></div>
       <div></div><div></div></div><span>Subscribe</span></button></div><div class="formkit-guarantee" data-element="guarantee" style="color: rgb(77, 77, 77); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">We won't send you spam. Unsubscribe at any time.</div><div class="formkit-powered-by-convertkit-container"><a href="https://convertkit.com?utm_source=dynamic&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=poweredby&amp;utm_content=form" data-element="powered-by" class="formkit-powered-by-convertkit" data-variant="dark" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Built with ConvertKit</a></div></div></form>
```

So what happens when you submit this form it obisouly goes to the action url which is off our site so I assum that's the problem,  but why would it work if I directly hit the url but not in an ajax request.

For example if I'm in another file and I do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  

 var email = "someemail@yahoo.com";
 var url = "/franchise_dashboard/testConvertKit.php";
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: email, // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
    
  
});
```

in the network is says it was a success but it did not submit the form like when you go directly to the file?

Comment: Ajax has CORS restrictions so if remote site doesn't enable CORS you can't make ajax request directly to it. Submitting form is different

Comment: Humm ok so you're saying that action url from convert kit has some setting blocking this form from being submitting with AJAX.  Or that's what is seems..